# How to Improve performance with Jetpack Compose (when assembling something inside a @Composable function)

Tags: android, performance, android-jetpack-compose

Suppose I have two composables in my app:

```
@Composable
fun CoreKeyboard(keyboardKeys: List<List<KeyboardKey>>, ...) {
    // ...
}
```

and

```
@Composable
fun NumberKeyboard(...) {
    val keyboardKeys = listOf(
        listOf(KeyboardKey("1"), KeyboardKey("2"), KeyboardKey("3")),
        listOf(KeyboardKey("4"), KeyboardKey("5"), KeyboardKey("6")),
        listOf(KeyboardKey("7"), KeyboardKey("8"), KeyboardKey("9")),
        listOf(KeyboardKey("0"))
    )

    CoreKeyboard(keyboardKeys = keyboardKeys, ...)

}
```

If I'm not wrong, this approach is not very performatic as in every recomposition the `keyboardKeys` in `NumberKeyboard` will be reassembled.

**What is the best way to do this?**

I thought about using `by remember { mutableStateOf(...) }`, but `keyboardKeys` is immutable. Is it still a good approach?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have something that is expensive to compute and you want to compute it on your composable only once, simply wrap it with `remember`

```
val keyboardKeys = remember {
    listOf(
    listOf(KeyboardKey("1"), KeyboardKey("2"), KeyboardKey("3")),
    listOf(KeyboardKey("4"), KeyboardKey("5"), KeyboardKey("6")),
    listOf(KeyboardKey("7"), KeyboardKey("8"), KeyboardKey("9")),
    listOf(KeyboardKey("0"))
    )
}
```

You only need the `mutableStateOf` if you want to mutate the value so that it can be observed.

Comment: Thats correct. But also check an issue: Calling Composable with same List<T> instance forces it to recompose https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/199496149

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer. I tried something similar earlier using the delegated property (`by remember`) but it didn't work ("Type 'TypeVariable(T)' has no method 'getValue(Nothing?, KProperty<*>)' and thus it cannot serve as a delegate"). But in your way it works just fine :)

Comment: @AugustoCarmo `by` needed when `remember` used with `mutableStateOf` to be updated later, in cases when there's no mutable state delegation is not needed.